# Proving $x*\ln(\ln(x))>\ln(\ln(x\#))$ for $\infty>$x>e$

Tags: number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers, logarithms, primorial

Let $x \in \mathbb{N}$.

For $\infty>x>e$,

Let $x$ be the largest prime in the factorization of the primorial $x\#$.

How does one go about proving $x*\ln(\ln(x))>\ln(\ln(x\#))$?

The plot of LHS$-$RHS looks like it will be always positive, so
heuristically it seems that there should be a simple proof, but
so far it has eluded me. Here is my attempt:

From the definition of the primorial, we easily have

$n*\ln(x)>\ln(x\#)$

where $n$ is the number of primes in $x$. Then,

$\ln(n)+\ln(\ln(x))>\ln(\ln(x\#))$

$x*\ln(\ln(x))>x*(\ln(\ln(x\#))-\ln(n))>\ln(\ln(x\#))-\ln(n)$

So, at least it's true for sufficiently small $n$.

Comment: Since $\lim_{y\to\infty} \ln(\ln(y)) = \infty$, this cannot be true absent some restriction relating $x,y$.  Is there any missing context for your question?

Answer (score 1):

$\ln(\ln y)$ is unbounded, that is, it can be made as large as you like for a large enough $y$. Without any other constraint on $x$ and $y$, the problem seems incomplete